# How does SQL's groupby work in an SQLite database?

Tags: android, kotlin, group-by, android-sqlite

I have the following class

```
data class ExtraAttributeFlatGroupEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = ID)
    @SerializedName(ID)
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = TYPE)
    @SerializedName(TYPE)
    val type: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = NAME_AR)
    @SerializedName(NAME_AR)
    val nameAr: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = NAME_EN)
    @SerializedName(NAME_EN)
    val nameEn: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = SYSTEM_NAME)
    @SerializedName(SYSTEM_NAME)
    val systemName: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = IS_REQUIRED)
    @SerializedName(IS_REQUIRED)
    val isRequired: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = DISPLAY_ORDER)
    @SerializedName(DISPLAY_ORDER)
    val displayOrder: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = MIN)
    @SerializedName(MIN)
    val min: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = MAX)
    @SerializedName(MAX)
    val max: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = VALIDATE_MIN)
    @SerializedName(VALIDATE_MIN)
    val validateMin: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = VALIDATE_MAX)
    @SerializedName(VALIDATE_MAX)
    val validateMax: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = SLIDER_STEPS)
    @SerializedName(SLIDER_STEPS)
    val sliderSteps: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = IS_INT)
    @SerializedName(IS_INT)
    val isInt: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = IMAGE)
    @SerializedName(IMAGE)
    val image: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = EXTRA_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID)
    @SerializedName(EXTRA_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID)
    val extraAttributeGroupId: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = SUB_TYPE)
    @SerializedName(SUB_TYPE)
    val subType: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = SCOPE)
    @SerializedName(SCOPE)
    val scope: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = GROUP_ID)
    @SerializedName(GROUP_ID)
    val groupId: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = GROUP_NAME_AR)
    @SerializedName(GROUP_NAME_AR)
    val groupNameAr: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = GROUP_NAME_EN)
    @SerializedName(GROUP_NAME_EN)
    val groupNameEn: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = GROUP_DISPLAY_ORDER)
    @SerializedName(GROUP_DISPLAY_ORDER)
    val groupDisplayOrder: Int

) {

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_ATTRIBUTES_FLAT_GROUP_TABLE = "extra_attributes_flat_group"
        const val ID = "id"
        const val NAME_AR = "name_ar"
        const val NAME_EN = "name_en"
        const val SYSTEM_NAME = "system_name"
        const val REGION_ID = "region_id"
        const val DISPLAY_ORDER = "display_order"
        const val IMAGE = "image"
        const val TYPE = "type"
        const val IS_REQUIRED = "is_required"
        const val MIN = "min"
        const val MAX = "max"
        const val VALIDATE_MIN = "validate_min"
        const val VALIDATE_MAX = "validate_max"
        const val SLIDER_STEPS = "slider_steps"
        const val IS_INT = "is_int"
        const val EXTRA_ATTRIBUTE_GROUP_ID = "extra_attribute_group_id"
        const val SUB_TYPE = "sub_type"
        const val SCOPE = "scope"
        const val IS_ACTIVE = "is_active"

        const val GROUP_ID = "group_id"
        const val GROUP_NAME_AR = "group_name_ar"
        const val GROUP_NAME_EN = "group_name_en"
        const val GROUP_DISPLAY_ORDER = "group_display_order"
    }
}
```

It compine results from two tables
it is filled by SQLite query from two tables

What I need is to convert that to map of group as a key and list of items inside it or even a simple object like

```
data class AttributeGroup(
    val attributeGroup: ExtraAttributeGroupEntity,
    val attributes: List<ExtraAttributeEntity>
)
```

The class ExtraAttributeGroupEntity is like

```
data class ExtraAttributeGroupEntity(
    @PrimaryKey()
    @ColumnInfo(name = ID)
    @SerializedName(ID)
    var id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = NAME_EN)
    @SerializedName(NAME_EN)
    val nameEn: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = NAME_AR)
    @SerializedName(NAME_AR)
    val nameAr: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = DISPLAY_ORDER)
    @SerializedName(DISPLAY_ORDER)
    val displayOrder: Int

) {}
```

And the other class have other values